# Symfony Password Reset without FOS Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make a form that users can easily change their password. I hope my logic is correct, however I'm getting an error as follows;

```
Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\ChangePasswordType" given
```

Here is my controller;

```
public function changePasswdAction(Request $request)
{
    $changePasswordModel = new ChangePassword();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), $changePasswordModel);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action,
        // such as encoding with MessageDigestPasswordEncoder and persist
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
    }

    return $this->render(':security:changepassword.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Here is my model;

```
class ChangePassword
{

/**
 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
 *     message = "Wrong value for your current password"
 * )
 */
protected $oldPassword;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min = 6,
 *     minMessage = "Password should by at least 6 chars long"
 * )
 */
protected $newPassword;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOldPassword()
{
    return $this->oldPassword;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $oldPassword
 */
public function setOldPassword($oldPassword)
{
    $this->oldPassword = $oldPassword;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getNewPassword()
{
    return $this->newPassword;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $newPassword
 */
public function setNewPassword($newPassword)
{
    $this->newPassword = $newPassword;
}
```

}

Here is my change password type;

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ChangePasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('oldPassword', 'password');
        $builder->add('newPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
        ));
    }

}
```

Here is my viewer;

```
{{ form_widget(form.current_password) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
```

The solution mentioned by @dragoste worked well for me. 
I changed the following line

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), $changePasswordModel);
```

with this line;

```
$form = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordType::class, $changePasswordModel);
```

Comment: problem is with `$this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), $changePasswordModel);` createForm expects a string as first argument.  Give the fully qualified class name as a string as per your bundle `'Your\Bundle\Form\ChangePasswordType'`.

Comment: actually its always better to do `ChangePasswordType::class` than manually put the class name. There are no suprises when refactoring the code ;-)

Comment: @dragoste This is worked very well! I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent Symfony releases you can pass only class name in `createForm`

Change

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), $changePasswordModel);
```

to

```
$form = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordType::class, $changePasswordModel);
```

Read more about building forms at
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#building-forms